# Linux try_cmpxchg mysterious inline assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, locking

I need some help understanding Linux's `try_cmpxchg semantics and implementation. In the kernel source, it is implemented as:

```
#define __raw_try_cmpxchg(_ptr, _pold, _new, size, lock)        \
({                                                              \
    bool success;                                               \
    __typeof__(_ptr) _old = (_pold);                            \
    __typeof__(*(_ptr)) __old = *_old;                          \
    __typeof__(*(_ptr)) __new = (_new);                         \
    switch (size) {                                             \
    case __X86_CASE_B:                                          \
    {                                                           \
        volatile u8 *__ptr = (volatile u8 *)(_ptr);             \
        asm volatile(lock "cmpxchgb %[new], %[ptr]"             \
                 CC_SET(z)                                      \
                 : CC_OUT(z) (success),                         \
                   [ptr] "+m" (*__ptr),                         \
                   [old] "+a" (__old)                           \
                 : [new] "q" (__new)                            \
                 : "memory");                                   \
        break;                                                  \
    }                                                           \
    case __X86_CASE_W:                                          \
    {                                                           \
        volatile u16 *__ptr = (volatile u16 *)(_ptr);           \
        asm volatile(lock "cmpxchgw %[new], %[ptr]"             \
                 CC_SET(z)                                      \
                 : CC_OUT(z) (success),                         \
                   [ptr] "+m" (*__ptr),                         \
                   [old] "+a" (__old)                           \
                 : [new] "r" (__new)                            \
                 : "memory");                                   \
        break;                                                  \
    }                                                           \
    case __X86_CASE_L:                                          \
    {                                                           \
        volatile u32 *__ptr = (volatile u32 *)(_ptr);           \
        asm volatile(lock "cmpxchgl %[new], %[ptr]"             \
                 CC_SET(z)                                      \
                 : CC_OUT(z) (success),                         \
                   [ptr] "+m" (*__ptr),                         \
                   [old] "+a" (__old)                           \
                 : [new] "r" (__new)                            \
                 : "memory");                                   \
        break;                                                  \
    }                                                           \
    case __X86_CASE_Q:                                          \
    {                                                           \
        volatile u64 *__ptr = (volatile u64 *)(_ptr);           \
        asm volatile(lock "cmpxchgq %[new], %[ptr]"             \
                 CC_SET(z)                                      \
                 : CC_OUT(z) (success),                         \
                   [ptr] "+m" (*__ptr),                         \
                   [old] "+a" (__old)                           \
                 : [new] "r" (__new)                            \
                 : "memory");                                   \
        break;                                                  \
    }                                                           \
    default:                                                    \
        __cmpxchg_wrong_size();                                 \
    }                                                           \
    if (unlikely(!success))                                     \
        *_old = __old;                                          \
    likely(success);                                            \
})

#define __try_cmpxchg(ptr, pold, new, size)     \
    __raw_try_cmpxchg((ptr), (pold), (new), (size), LOCK_PREFIX)

#define try_cmpxchg(ptr, pold, new)                 \
    __try_cmpxchg((ptr), (pold), (new), sizeof(*(ptr)))
```

I am curious what those `CC_SET` and `CC_OUT` means. They are defined as:

```
/*
 * Macros to generate condition code outputs from inline assembly,
 * The output operand must be type "bool".
 */
#ifdef __GCC_ASM_FLAG_OUTPUTS__
# define CC_SET(c) "\n\t/* output condition code " #c "*/\n"
# define CC_OUT(c) "=@cc" #c
#else
# define CC_SET(c) "\n\tset" #c " %[_cc_" #c "]\n"
# define CC_OUT(c) [_cc_ ## c] "=qm"
#endif
```

Also, it would be great if you can explain the exact semantics of `try_cmpxchg` (not quite understand how can a atomic `cmpxchg` fail...)

Comment: `CC_SET` and `CC_OUT` are macros. They deal with condition codes; specifically, telling the compiler through its extended inline assembly syntax how the instructions in the inline assembly block affect condition codes (i.e., CPU flags). The [documentation](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_41.html) for the `CMPXCHG` instruction tells you how it affects flags.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of gcc (I believe from version 6) support specific flag outputs. The macros are there to use this support if available, else fall back to the old way by doing a `setCC` instruction and a temporary output.

As to how `cmpxchg` can "fail": it does a compare so it fails if that compare fails, in which case the destination is unchanged and the current value is fetched from memory. Consult an instruction set reference for the details.

Comment: Ah... I know that a `cmpxchg` can fail, but what is the difference between `cmpxchg()` and `try_cmpxchg()`?

Comment: See [this commit message](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg.h?id=a9ebf306f52c756c4f9e50ee9a60cd6389d71344). TL;DR: the `try` version returns a boolean indication, for the other, you have to test the old value. The `try` is better and more readable, the other is kept for compatibility.